# Normalize an image using the mean pixel value in a ROI

Tags: imagej

I want to normalize several images in imageJ using the mean pixel value in a ROI, so that after normalization the mean in this ROI has the same value in all the images. How can I do it?  Thanks

Comment: This question is not a programming question, and therefore off-topic on stackoverflow. Please consider asking on https://forum.image.sc/ as suggested in the `imagej` tag description.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say with out a particular example but a priory I would select the ROI and press `control + M`to measure the region. If it is grey scale image you should obtain the gray mean of the grey pixels. You can use then this value to divide all the pixels in you image using `Divide` function under the `Process > Math` menu. If you calculate the mean for each image and use that value to divide each corresponding image, your ROI should have the same mean value for all ROI in your pictures.

I hope it helps!